# Как получить вложения прикрепленные к другой странице в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Не могу на странице с id=803 получить список вложений, прикрепленных к странице с id=215. На странице с id=215 список отображается корректно. Подскажите что я делаю не так?

```
echo $post->ID;  
if ($post->ID == 803) {
 $id = 215;
} else {
 $id = $post->ID;
}
echo $id;
$media = get_attached_media( 'image', $id );
print_r( $media );
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то не то получаете. Для того чтобы получить все аттачменты поста:

```
$attachments = new WP_Query( [
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent'    => $post_id,
    'fields'         => 'ids'
] );

print_r( $attachments->posts );
```

Comment: Конкретно, я хочу получить изображения прикрепленные к другой странице.

Comment: $post_id меняйте и все